# Espressione "potenti mezzi"

Tags: idioms

Spesso mi capita di sentire, leggere o utilizzare l'espressione "I potenti mezzi...", quasi sempre come incipit ironico e sarcastico.

Ma da dove deriva? È un riferimento a qualche frase famosa o è solo una consuetudine senza una particolare origine?

Comment: È abbastanza comune usare un'esagerazione per affermare il contrario/ironizzare in qualche modo di quello che si dice.

Comment: Trovo la domanda interessante, e purtroppo non ho la più pallida idea della risposta. Se mi costringessero a formulare un'ipotesi, cercherei l'origine in qualche stilema fascista da cinegiornale e simili, che poi si sia diffuso con tono derisorio.

Answer (score 2):

Guardando [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20potenti%20mezzi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpotenti%20mezzi%3B%2Cc0) sembra che l'espressione 'potenti mezzi' fosse più in uso in passato che ora. Potrebbe forse avere una relazione con  i maggiori periodi bellici, ma in realtà l'uso è diminuito gradualmente dall'inizio del '900.

Non penso che l'espressione abbia un'origine precisa. Mi sembra più un comune modo di dire in riferimento a qualcosa di cospicuo ed efficace.